# how to convert string of unicode to string of hexa in c++

Tags: c++, string, unicode, type-conversion, hex

I have this sample of code, which aims to write some data in a stream so I later can read it again.

```
std::ostringstream oss;
int a = 10;
oss.write((char*)&a, sizeof(int));
a = 5;
oss.write((char*)&a, sizeof(int));
// etc...

std::cout << oss.str();
```

I'm trying to unit test this sample, which is the reason why i'd like to manipulate some understandable data.

The thing is that oss.str() seems to return a string of unicode data such : "\u0000\u0000\u0000@\u000a�#<\u0000\u0000�?"

I'd like to retrieve this string of int under a string a hexa format such as '\0x0a\0x80\0x3f\0x3c" instead but i can't figure out how to manage to do it. I'm pretty not familiar with the std library..

Thanks in advance for any tips !

Comment: *The thing is that oss.str() seems to return a string of unicode data* -- The data in the string is not "unicode".  It is just bytes, and it is the way that your debugger, output routine, whatever, happens to display the data.  [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/rP6ehbsqz)

Comment: Those are the bytes you wrote to the stream, interpreted as a string; `'\u0000'` is zero.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the representation. `"\0x0a\0x80\0x3f\0x3c"` is a string of four characters, not a string of hexadecimal digits. In ASCII, the first is the newline character, the second is unprintable, and the two final ones are `'?'` and `'<'`.

Comment: Note: `int` is 4 bytes. You are writing 4 bytes per character, of which 3 are 0 bytes. If you wanted to write a character at a time, call `oss.put(10)` (or `oss.put(0x0a)`) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question looks like you are trying to convert binary data to a hex string.

You may try following to achive that.

```
std::string binaryData = oss.str();
std::ostringstream hexStream;
hexStream << std::hex << std::setfill('0');

for (unsigned char byte : binaryData) {
    hexStream << "\\x" << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(byte);
}

std::cout << hexStream.str() << std::endl;
```